# Eclipse same name file include path c c++

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, path, include

First of all I like to mention that I am using eclipse.

This is the example file structure

source/file.h
source/additionalsource/file.h

thing to note is that both header files have the same name.

so including source/ and source/additionsource  to include paths and writing #include "file.h" Does not work since there is conflict of file names.

So I only included the source/ in the include paths and I am using #include "file.h" and "additionlsource/file.h" in my code.

For some reason eclipse does not find the additionsource/file.h even though source/ is in the include path.

This work in visual studio and GNU makefiles but not in eclipse.

I do not want to change the files as it is a share project and cross platform application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include "./additionalsource/file.h"
```